# Unity Character Controller Script bug

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

I am using the Script from unity scripting reference :
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 6.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
    public float gravity = 20.0F;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    void Update() {
        CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        if (controller.isGrounded) {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

        }
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

But Problem is that , When I have built it its shows the following errors

[image]

Has there any solution ?

Comment: Do other scripts work, or all give error on using UnityEngine; ?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding? Failing that, delete the asset and re-import, but if Unity is unable to find it's own namespace, it's pretty terminal. If you remove the scripts from your objects/prefabs, can you compile and run?

Comment: Unity automatically builds saved scripts. You don't have to build anything. External editors may not know about all assemblies Unity is using and trying to build code in them is not necessary and likely to fail. So I'm not sure there is an actual problem here, unless you're stating that it doesn't work inside Unity either.

Comment: Yes .JavaScript is Ok and no Problem . C# Script are unable to attach with game object due to messaged fix errors .

Comment: Show us the errors you get in the Unity console. Those are important and revealing. If they are the same as the ones you show, your installation has problem.

Comment: But I think its really a problem .causes i have installed a new  version of Unity in my second PC and displays same errors

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I see is to use Visual Studio 2015 because MonoDevelop works horrible in last Unity versions. But then JavaScripts won't work. By the way, VS2015 Community can be installed from Unity installer starting from Unity 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

This happens (also with Visual Studio) sometimes if you add a new  / move a Script inside of Unity.

The only solution I found until now is closing both Unity and the Editor, go to the Folder on your harddrive and remove the *.csproj and evtl. the *.sln files.
(In worst case you also can try to remove the Library folder it is also builded by Unity)

Then relunch Unity and the Editor. Now it should rebuild the project and parse correctly.